# Discount on shipping rate coming from ups

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, magento-community, shipping-methods, magento-ce

I want to give 15% discount on shipping rate that I get from ups in magento.any idea ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We use an extension provided by Amasty that allows this.  You can set it to work for all orders, or orders to certain destinations or orders totaling over a certain amount...

This is the link to the extension
http://amasty.com/shipping-rules.html

And on magento Connect:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-rules-by-amasty.html

I am not affiliated with the developer nor do I receive any benefits from recommending their extensions

Comment: Thank you.I have bought another extension by webshopapps but it is not working.I asked for support but didnt get any reply

Comment: Does it support for different store.for eg in one store we want to give 15% discount nd on other we want to give 20%.

Comment: Yes, you can specify per store and per customer group